# Storing values from a CSV file to a dynamic char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to store certain values from a CSV file which contains the following details in a dynamic char array. I am able to read the CSV file and have provided the code for that in the description below. I would appreciate if anyone could please let me know what approach shall I use to store certain data from a row in a CSV in a dynamic char array. Thanks! I have also written a substring function which returns a particular string by putting the parameters of starting index, end index and source.

CSV File :- 
place,name,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20 
I want to store the dates after Long (without commas) in a dynamic char array(I cannot use vectors) Thanks!

```
char* substring(char* source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int size = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
    char* s = new char[size+1];
    strncpy(s, source + startIndex, size); 
    s[size]  = '\0'; //make it null-terminated
    return s;
} 

char** readCSV(const char* csvFileName, int& csvLineCount)
{
    ifstream fin(csvFileName);
    if (!fin)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    csvLineCount = 0;
    char line[1024];
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want char arrays? `vector` would make your life much easier.

Comment: @cigien  I was able to do with the vectors easily, but I now I am trying with arrays. Thanks!

Comment: Generally each line of a csv represents a "record" of data that can be composed of differing types. If you define a `struct` where the members match each field in the csv, you can create a `std:vector<yourstruct>` and fill one element per line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have done that using vectors, but, now I am trying to use dynamic char arrays to store these values

Comment: You have chosen an annoying path. People don't do this for good reasons. Now that you've read the line with `fin.getline(line, 1024);` you want to split the line into its constituent tokens, yes?

Comment: `char** readCSV(const char* csvFileName, int& csvLineCount)` looks fine for that purpose. Are you getting errors or having problems? Rather than `char* substring(char* source, int startIndex, int endIndex)`, if you go the `char *` route, then `char* substring(char* source, char *start, char *end)` may allow a bit more direct use of pointers to extract the substring. (you can use `end - start` for `size`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   I am still not able to store the data in the dynamic char array. I have created the dynamic char array but don't know how to store the values(the dates) in the array (without commas)

Comment: What do you want in the individual char array?  `"1/22/20"` or `"1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20"`? Or do you want 3 elements per file row?

Comment: @SergeBallesta  for example, n is dynamic char array:- n[0] = 1/22/20 , n[1] = 1/23/20 and so on. Thanks

Comment: And are there always 3 dates per row?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Actually there are a total of 80 dates, but I have shown only 3 above.

Comment: How many lines and columns in your csv file? And what is variable here only the number of lines or both the number of lines and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment that you are still having problems dynamically allocating for the lines read from the csv file (and with the caveat, programs today should avoid the old pointer-to-pointer to char in favor of vector of strings) -- one reason is you are approaching the allocation of pointers in an inefficient manner. Instead of a single pass through your input file, you make 2-passes through your file, one to read the number of lines (to allocate pointers), and then again to read and allocate storage for each line. While that is one approach -- it is a very inefficient approach since file I/O is one of the least efficient tasks you can perform (and you do it twice)

Instead, simply allocate some initial number of pointers (1 or 2 or 8 is a good starting point). You then keep track of the number of allocated pointers available (say with `size_t avail = 2;` and the number of pointers used (say `size_t used = 0;`). Then as you are reading lines you check `if (used == available)` to know when it is time to reallocate more pointers. You can simply reallocate 2X the current number of pointers using a temporary `char**` pointer. You then copy the existing pointers to `tmp`, `delete[] lines;` and then assign the new block of memory containing the pointers back to `lines`.

Another change to make is to open your `std::ifstream` file stream in `main()`, validate it is open for reading, and then pass a reference to the open stream as a parameter to your function instead of passing the filename (if you can't successfully open the stream in the caller -- there is no need to make the function call to count lines)

To read the lines from your stream handling the allocations as you go, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXC 1024

char **readcsv (std::ifstream& fin, size_t& csvLineCount)
{
    size_t avail = 2, used = 0;                     /* allocated/used counters */
    char line[MAXC], **lines = new char*[avail];    /* line and lines */

    while (fin.getline (line, MAXC)) {              /* loop reading each line */
        size_t len;                                 /* for line length */
        if (used == avail) {                        /* all pointers used? */
            char **tmp = new char *[2 * avail];     /* allocate twice as many */
            memcpy (tmp, lines, used * sizeof *lines);  /* copy lines to new tmp */
            delete[] lines;                         /* free existing pionters */
            lines = tmp;                            /* set lines to new block */
            avail *= 2;                             /* update ptrs available */
        }
        lines[used] = new char[(len = strlen(line)) + 1];   /* alloc for lines[used] */
        memcpy (lines[used++], line, len + 1);      /* copy line to lines[used] */
    }
    csvLineCount = used;                            /* update csvLineCount to used */

    return lines;       /* return lines */
}
```

Adding a short `main()` that takes the filename to read as the first argument to the program and opens the stream in `main()` before passing a reference to the open stream to your read function would be:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input.\n"
                     "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    char **lines = nullptr;         /* pointer-to-pointer to char */
    size_t nlines = 0;              /* line counter */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);      /* file stream */

    if (!f.is_open()) {     /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(lines = readcsv (f, nlines))) {   /* call line read function/validate */
        std::cerr << "error: readcsv() failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nlines; i++) {   /* loop outputting lines, freeing memory */
        std::cout << lines[i] << '\n';
        delete[] lines[i];                  /* free lines */
    }
    delete[] lines;                         /* free pointers */
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/latlon.csv
place1,name1,Lat1,Long1,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place2,name2,Lat2,Long2,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place3,name3,Lat3,Long3,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place4,name4,Lat4,Long4,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
```

**Example Use/Output**

All lines successfully stored in allocated memory:

```
$ ./bin/read_alloc_csv_lines dat/latlon.csv
place1,name1,Lat1,Long1,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place2,name2,Lat2,Long2,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place3,name3,Lat3,Long3,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place4,name4,Lat4,Long4,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/read_alloc_csv_lines dat/latlon.csv
==8108== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8108== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8108== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8108== Command: ./bin/read_alloc_csv_lines dat/latlon.csv
==8108==
place1,name1,Lat1,Long1,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place2,name2,Lat2,Long2,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place3,name3,Lat3,Long3,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
place4,name4,Lat4,Long4,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20
==8108==
==8108== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8108==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8108==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 82,712 bytes allocated
==8108==
==8108== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8108==
==8108== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8108== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

I have left handling the substring to you since your comment pertained to problems reading the lines into allocated memory. If you have problems with that later, just let me know. Also let me know if you have any further questions about how things were done above.

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me know if you have questions on it and I'm happy to help further. Seeing it all put together helps sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I would slightly change your code to iterate the fields of the header line instead of iterating the lines of a file:

```
char* substring(const char *start, const char *end)
{
    int size = end - start + 1;
    char* s = new char[size + 1];
    strncpy(s, start, size);
    s[size] = '\0'; //make it null-terminated
    return s;
}

char** readHeaderDates(const char* csvFileName, int& csvDateCount)
{
    ifstream fin(csvFileName);
    if (!fin)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    csvDateCount = 0;
    char line[1024];
    if (! fin.getline(line, 1024))   // read header line
    {
        return nullptr;
    };
    fin.close();
    // count commas in line:
    for (const char *ix = line;; ix = strchr(ix, ',')) {
        if (NULL == ix) break;
        csvDateCount += 1;
        ix += 1;
    }
    csvDateCount -= 3;
    if (csvDateCount <= 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    char **dates = new char*[csvDateCount];
    const char *ix = line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ix = strchr(ix, ',') + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<csvDateCount; i++)
    {
        const char *start = ix;
        const char *end = strchr(ix, ',');
        if (nullptr == end) end = start + strlen(start);
        dates[i] = substring(start, end);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

BEWARE: untested code...

Comment: Thanks a lot brother for your help! Highly appreciate your efforts