# Dynamically Allocated array of pointers to structures in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic

I have created the following structure. I am trying to create a dynamic array of Place in which I want to store the values of the char members of the struct(region, state)

I have written the following code to access its members , but I am not able to print anything on the screen. I would highly appreciate if anyone could please help me out with this problem. Thanks!

```
struct Place {
char* region = nullptr; //region, in dynamic char array (C-string)
char* state = nullptr; //state, in dynamic char array (C-string)
};

Place** places = new Place*[1000];

places[0]->region = substring(CurrentLine, t, a[t]-1);

places[1]->region =  substring(CurrentLine, n, a[n+1]-1);

places[2]->province =  substring(CurrentLine, n, a[n+1]-1);

return *places;

delete[] places;
places = nullptr;
```

Comment: `places[0]` is a pointer to nowhere. You allocated storage for `places`, but nothing for the next dimension. Looking over this a bit more, I don't think you need that extra extra level of indirection. `Place* places = new Place[1000];` ought to be enough.

Comment: Well, this is just for an example, I just want to ask about how to access members of a struct and store it in a dynamic array

Comment: In that case you have allocated storage for `1000` pointers (they are currently uninitialized). You must now loop reading your data and allocating storage for each struct, e.g. `places[0] = new Place;`. Then you can fill the struct, e.g. `places[0]->region = ...` The general approach would be to allocate some minimum number of pointers, and then reallocate additional pointers as needed. Up to you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can share my entire code with you if you want?

Comment: The general recommendation is that you back up your code, then hack the code down to the minimum needed to get your point across. It needs to compile (or not compile because of the the one error you're asking about) and, with as little human interaction as possible, produce the undesired behaviour. This makes sure we see exactly what you're seeing and quite often the reduced amount of noise around the bug makes the bug obvious and you fix it

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7, yes, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with a few lines of sample input to show us what you are filling your struct with (and how you approach reading it)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If possible can we continue this conversation in private?

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 *"I just want to ask about how to access members of a struct and store it in a dynamic array"* -- storing the struct in a dynamic array is what user4581301 suggested. Your code is more accurately described as "store *pointers to it* in a dynamic array".

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, that's my question how to access members of a struct and store it in a dynamic array?

Comment: Somewhere there is a button to more to chat -- though I never can seem to find it unless it just pops up after X-number of comments are entered. It may also have something to do with rep points.

Comment: @JaMiTIt would be great if you could give me an example. Thanks!

Comment: [Example Dynamically Allocating for Pointer-to-Pointer to char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373626/3422102), you will just use your struct instead of `char`. The allocation takes place in the `readcsv()` function. The approach to handling dynamic allocation for any  pointer-to-pointer to type will be the same.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah I can't find it either! I guess it requires a couple more comments:)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Alright! Thanks a lot! I am trying to figure it out! Will ask for any help if needed

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 Your example code should match your question. Since your question is about storing a struct in a dynamic array, your code should demonstrate storing a struct in a dynamic array. Currently it does not; it demonstrates having **a pointer to** a struct in a dynamic array. You ask about an array of structures; you show an array of pointers, which is not the same thing.